# How to handle two different JSON responses with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, urlsession

I am making a login functionality in a SwiftUI app.
When the login in successful the JSON response is:

```
    {
    "user_id": 41,
    "token": "Token",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 12096000
    }
```

When the login is failed the JSON response is:

```
{
 "message": "this is a failure message"
}
```

I made two different structs to encode the responses

```
struct LoginResponseModelFailure:Codable {
    let message:String
}

struct LoginResponseModelSuccess:Codable{
    let user_id: Int
    let token: String
    let token_type : String
    let expires_in: Int
}
```

Do I need to merge these two structs to single one? if so how to do that?
How can I handle two different responses using alamofire or urlSession?

Comment: You could merge them into one and make message optional. If it’s nil then success, otherwise fail

Answer (score 6):

To avoid optionals my suggestion is to declare the root object as enum with associated values

```
enum Response : Decodable {
    case success(ResponseSuccess)
    case failure(ResponseFailure)
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = .success(try container.decode(ResponseSuccess.self))
        } catch {
            self = .failure(try container.decode(ResponseFailure.self))
        }
    }
}
```

The other structs can remain as they are except the names became *camelCase*

```
struct ResponseFailure : Decodable {
    let message : String
}

struct ResponseSuccess : Decodable {
    let userId : Int
    let token : String
    let tokenType : String
    let expiresIn : Int
}
```

To decode the data `switch` on the result, `data` represents the received raw data. The key decoding strategy is added to handle the *snake_case* keys

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    switch result {
        case .success(let data): print(data)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I've never seen something like that before, but it looks like a nice solutions. I will copy your implementation next time.

Comment: this one doesn't work at all..because even if its not success..it wont go to failure...alwat success nil is shown

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, one way is to create one `Struct` but then you have to make all the properties `Optional` as below,

```
struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    let user_id: Int?
    let token: String?
    let token_type : String?
    let expires_in: Int?
    let message: String?
}
```

So now you have to deal with all the optionals.

Another way that seems more appropriate is to introduce another `Struct` that holds success and failure but you have to implement the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method as below,

```
struct LoginFailure: Codable {
    let message:String
}

struct LoginSuccess: Codable {
    let user_id: Int
    let token: String
    let token_type : String
    let expires_in: Int
}

struct LoginRespone: Codable {
    var data: LoginSuccess?
    var message: LoginFailure?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let data = try? container.decode(LoginSuccess.self) {
            self.data = data
        } else {
            self.message = try container.decode(LoginFailure.self)
        }
    }
}

let success = """
    {
    "user_id": 41,
    "token": "Token",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 12096000
    }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let failure = """
    {
    "message": "this is a failure message"
    }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

    do {
        let r = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginRespone.self, from: failure)
        print(r.message?.message)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one structure to handle the response. Based on status code, you can differentaite the response.

```swift
struct LoginModel:Codable {
    let message:String
    let userId: Int
    let token: String
    let tokenType : String
    let expiresIn: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys : String,CodingKey {
        case message, token
        case userId = "user_id"
        case tokenType = "token_type"
        case expiresIn = "expires_in"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let value = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.message = try value.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message) ?? ""
        self.userId = try value.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .userId) ?? 0
        self.token = try value.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .token) ?? ""
        self.tokenType = try value.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tokenType) ?? ""
        self.expiresIn = try value.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .expiresIn) ?? 0
    }
}
```